# Why are my Adsense ads taking the dimensions of the last ad on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, ads, adsense

It seems to appear that my ads are taking the dimensions of the very last ad on the page, causing all previous ads to be cropped. Any info on why this may be happening?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCBrt.jpg)

Example - http://mypetwantsthis.com/category/dog/clothing-dog/

Comment: can you point us to a page with an example of the problem. I'm guessing it's picking up the wrong parameters from the script (last set of dimensions applying everywhere)

Comment: Just added a URL to page on which it's occurring. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: the only thing I can see is on your first instance the parameters don't match the standard sizes (601), and on the second you're missing the height parameter. Also have you checked the console (in developer tools for your browser) to see if you're getting any errors from AdSense?